# Adding Cancel button to RadFileExplorer Upload window

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using radfile explorer. I'm trying to add Cancel button which will close the Upload window of RadfileExplorer. I want to add this button next to Upload button.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following threads will show you how to customize the dialogs:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-upload-file-fields

http://www.telerik.com/forums/upload-dialog

Here is an example that will get a reference to the currently opened dialog (which, when your custom button is added will always be the Upload dialog):

```
var explorer = $find("<%=FileExplorer1.ClientID%>");
var wndManager = explorer.get_windowManager(); //get reference to RadFileExplorer's window manager
var wnd = wndManager.getActiveWindow();//get reference to the upload dialog's window
wnd.close();
```